# Extract group name from `id` and store it in a variable

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk, grep

```
$ id usera
uid=830(usera) gid=799(groupa) groups=799(groupa)
```

I need to extract the group name from the output of id and store it in a variable. In this case it's `groupname=groupa`

Comment: are you looking for the `gid` or `groups`?

Answer (score 19):

`id` also accepts paramters, so you don't have to `grep` for it (`-g` to print only the group, and `-n` to print names instead of ids):

```
$ id -gn usera
groupa
```

To save that into a variable use that:

```
groupname=$(id -gn usera)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you search for more common solution (UNIX/Linux) you can use something like:

```
GROUP=$(id |awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[=(]" } ; { print $4 }')
```